# Powershell parameter will not provide OleDbdataAdapter.fill valid SQL statement

Tags: powershell

I has been trying to figure out why I am not able to use a parameter in the powershell script to fill in a datatable via OleDBDataAdapter. Here a snippet of the code and the error I am getting.

```
Function DBF_FileImport
{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$tblTemp,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [string]$strSQL = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
 )

### ConnectionString to pull data from DBF file ###
$ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
Source=$filepath;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=;"
$Conn = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connString)
$Conn.open()

#Create the new recordset
$cmd = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
$cmd.Connection = $Conn
$cmd.CommandText = "$strSQL"

#create the datatable
$da = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd)

$dt = new-object System.Data.dataTable
$da.fill($dt)

$Conn.close()
```

The error I receive every time I run the function is:

Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid SQL statement; 
expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."
At userpath.ps char:1
+ $da.fill($dt)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OleDbException

If I put the SQL statement inside the function then it works fine. I dont know why it is behaving like this. I searched the internet and was not able to find anything that will help me to solve the error. Any info you can provide will help greatly. Thank you

Comment: As for "If I put the SQL statement inside the function then it works fine. " Any reason you need /want to do this outside the function, since it works in it? Also, unless you have more of the errmsg, that message says it's failing on the $da.fill($dt), not one of the params in your param block.

Comment: Could you show the `-strSQL` argument you pass to the script?

Comment: It is resolved. It is odd but if I call the function and assign the values to the parameters via command line, then it will fine. In this example, I ran the function without any parameters then type in the values manually for each parameter which didn't worked correctly.